# Масштабирование картинок из drawable

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте! Суть в следующем. Есть самодельное меню из картинок, при портретной ориентации находится вверху при ландшафтной слева.
Вначале все прекрасно масштабировалось при нахождении картинок в `drawable`, в зависимости от разрешения. После того как я отправил загрузил код на SVN сервер. Друго пользователь изменил некоторые файлы, они отношения не имеют к формированию изображения, и масштабировать перестало. Использовал IDEA 10.5, после заливания перешел на 11 версию. Android 2.1, а коллеги Android 2.1-update1. Сверял все файлы одинаковые, вчем может быть дело?

Comment: Странно это все. Может все же был конфликт и нужный код потерся или изменился коллегой?

Comment: Извиняюсь версия 2.1, проблема была может из-за перехода с версии 2.0 на 2.1
Сейчас примерное решение найдено, протестировано только в эмуляторе, для 2.1, когда протестирую и для других API + на таблетке с версией 2.2, тогда отпишусь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перестаньте использовать SVN. В 3-м тысячилетье есть более правильные SCM-системы